# Как записать математическое выражение со степенями?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Надо записать выражение со степенями и вывести именно выражение в консоль, а не его результат. Пробовал через юникод, но он не отображает степень.

Comment: Выводите `a^b`...

Comment: `но он не отображает степень` не может быть! 42¹⁰⁰⁵⁰⁰